# Input box in Access VBA not appearing

Tags: ms-access, vba

Hi this was asked before but there was no answer.
I want to test out InputBox, however it won't appear when I trigger it via form.

```
Private Sub Command24_Click()
    Dim MyValue As String
    MyValue = InputBox("Please enter a #")
    Debug.Print "Test: "; MyValue
End Sub
```

There are no errors in the code, however nothing (besides the Debug.print) appears.

This is my code for the `InputBox` function:

```
Public Function InputBox( _
            ByVal Prompt As String, _
            Optional ByVal Title As String = "", _
            Optional ByVal DefaultResponse As String = "", _
            Optional ByVal Xpos As Integer = -1, _
            Optional ByVal YPos As Integer = -1 _
        ) As String
End Function
```

Comment: It has to work. Try to comment out the current code and - after the Debug line - _rewrite_ (no copy-n-paste) the code.

Comment: The code (these 3 lines) work for me in a command button on a form. @Keny

Comment: I tried re-writing my code (no copy-n-paste), still no good
this is my InputBox function in case something is wrong there
`Public Function InputBox( _
   ByVal Prompt As String, _
Optional ByVal Title As String = "", _
Optional ByVal DefaultResponse As String = "", _
Optional ByVal Xpos As Integer = -1, _
Optional ByVal YPos As Integer = -1 _
) As String

End Function`

Comment: Try commenting out those three lines and simply doing `MsgBox "Hello"`. Does that display the message box?

Comment: @GordThompson Yes it does

Comment: Okay, try changing the name of your custom function to `myInputBox` and see if that helps. `InputBox` is a built-in VBA function so creating your own custom function with the same name may be causing some confusion.

Comment: @GordThompson still no prompt input msg

Comment: OK, very interesting. After changing name of original function "InputBox" to "MyInputBox", running test = myinputbox("test") won't work. However test= inputbox("test") WILL work. Seems like I didn't need to add my function after all

Comment: Ah, I love secret code (only revealed in a later edit) that even does nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[InputBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251811.aspx) is a built-in VBA function. You don't need to create your own `Function InputBox` definition, just call the built-in function directly:

```vbs
Dim MyValue As String
MyValue = InputBox("Please enter something")
' no other code required
```